# Sourcing a shell profile in an ant build file?

Tags: ant, makefile, cruisecontrol

I am using cruisecontrol and ant to build some legacy executables that also depend on a shell profile to setup env vars properly. Is there a way to exec this profile using ant in the current process so the makefiles ant calls get the env vars correctly?

Another solution would be if there is a way to add the profile sourcing to the sub make files I'm calling.

Edit: I guess I wasn't clear in my question. I know what env varibles need to be passed to make using the exec/env tasks. However, I don't know how to have ant grab the values from a shell profile that is usually sourced via: `. /usr/local/profile/foo.profile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it based off of how ant itself sources env variables.

```
<exec executable="ksh" dir="${foo.dir}" 
      failonerror="true" output="${foo.dir}/env.properties">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value=". /usr/local/profiles/profile.foo; set" />
</exec>
<property file="${foo.dir}/env.properties" prefix="env"/>
```

Further down I can then pass them to sub make calls using the exec tags. For example:

```
<exec executable="make" dir="${bar.dir}" failonerror="true">
    <env key="ORACLE_HOME" value="${env.ORACLE_HOME}" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to execute make in the current process.

Take a look at the ant [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task, use this to execute your `make` build.  The environment variables will still be available for the make process, in fact you can turn this off explicitly with the `newenvironment` attribute.  The following simple exec should retain all environment variables in make:

```
<exec executable="make" />
```

If you need extra environment variables, or want to maintain them through your ant build you can use them in the exec task by adding `<env>` elements like so:

```
<exec executable="make" >
    <env key="ENV_KEY" value="ENV_VALUE"/>
</exec>
```